# Javascript readAsArrayBuffer from url

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to read binary file from url?

```
var url = 'http://example.com/image/abc.jpg';
var reader= new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // whatever
});
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(url);
```

Above example is not working (url is not a object).

```
var file = new File([""], "url");
```

is empty

Comment: Do you want to download the file?

Comment: I want to read the last 16 bytes from the file to compare with another. The file is on the same server.

Comment: Use Ajax + byte Range request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `HTTP GET` to get the file. Maybe this is what you need?

```js
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.response);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync("http://cdn.androidbeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/google-logo.jpg", res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

URL in your case is a string object. You need to use HTTP get in this case. [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript) and read the response.